# 1.2 Business: Payments - Subscriptions

Tags: xcode, in-app-purchase

My App keeps rejecting since month i don't know what the real issue,when i submit app fo review they take almost more then 2 weeks and app get rejected after two weeks 
this time app rejeceted due to this issue please guide me

Guideline 2.3.3 - Performance - Accurate Metadata

We noticed that your screenshots do not sufficiently reflect your app in use.

Specifically, your 6.5-inch iPhone screenshots do not display the app in the correct device frame.

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your screenshots to ensure that they accurately reflect the app in use on the supported devices. For iPhone, you need a set of 5.5-inch display screenshots and for iPad, you need a set for 12.9-inch display. This set will be scaled appropriately down to other device sizes when viewed on the App Store in each territory.

Note that 6.5-inch display assets for iPhone XS Max are optional, and can scale down to iPhone XR, iPhone XS, and iPhone X. Screenshots that include features like rounded corners or sensor housing should only be used for the 6.5-inch or 5.8-inch display.

Resources

For resources on creating great screenshots for the App Store, you may want to review the App Store Product Page information available on the Apple Developer website.

Please ensure you have made any screenshot modifications using Media Manager. You should confirm your app looks and behaves identically in all languages and on all supported devices. Learn more about uploading app previews and screenshots in App Store Connect Help.

Guideline 3.1.2 - Business - Payments - Subscriptions

We also still noticed that your app's metadata did not fully meet the terms and conditions for auto-renewing subscriptions, as specified in Schedule 2, section 3.8(b) of the Paid Applications agreement.

App Store Information
We were unable to find the following App Store Information items in App Store Connect.

– Information about the auto-renewable nature of the subscription in your app's description:
• Title of publication or service
• Length of subscription (time period and content or services provided during each subscription period)
• Payment will be charged to iTunes Account at confirmation of purchase
• Subscription automatically renews unless auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the current period
• Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours prior to the end of the current period, and identify the cost of the renewal
• Subscriptions may be managed by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to the user's Account Settings after purchase
• Any unused portion of a free trial period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a subscription to that publication, where applicable
– A link to the terms of use in either the app description or EULA field

Next Steps

To resolve this issue, please revise your app's metadata to include this missing information. If the above information is in your app, please reply to this message in Resolution Center to provide details on where to locate it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the information they're saying in your App Store Description.

Below is a template you can use:

> Subscription to [your product name] will be charged to iTunes Account at
>   confirmation of purchase. Subscription automatically renews unless
>   auto-renew is turned off at least 24-hours before the end of the
>   current period. Account will be charged for renewal within 24-hours
>   prior to the end of the current period. Subscriptions may be managed
>   by the user and auto-renewal may be turned off by going to your
>   Account Settings after purchase. Any unused portion of a free trial
>   period, if offered, will be forfeited when the user purchases a
>   subscription to that publication, where applicable. Read our Terms &
>   Privacy Policy here: [your privacy policy url]

Also, this may be a helpful post on [Getting Through App Store Review](https://medium.com/revenuecat-blog/getting-through-app-review-39ac50438c62)